# Как задать суффикс для TimedRotatingFileHandler в конфигурации?

Tags: python, логирование

У меня есть конфигуарция для настройки логирования:

```
"file_handler": {
    "class": "logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler",
    "level": "DEBUG",
    "formatter": "simple",
    "filename": "development.log",
     "encoding": "utf8"
}
```

Конфигурация, как видно из примера, является `JSON`-объектом. Загрузка и применение конфигуарции банальна и проста: сначала чтение файла, затем интерпретация модулем `json` из стандартной библиотеки и затем вызов `dict_config`.

Меня не устраивается имя файла для лога после ротации. Оно весьма неудобно, тем что имеет временную метку в качестве расширения файла. Очень хочу вынести в базовое имя, а расширение пусть будет 'log'.

Я нашел решение моей проблемы, оно написано на enSO: [TimedRotatingFileHandler Changing File Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338450/timedrotatingfilehandler-changing-file-name). Но это решение мне не очень-то нравится. Оно для runtime, а мне бы хотелось задавать декларативно, т.е. в конфигурации.

Возможно ли такое и если да, то - как?

Answer (score 3):

В свое время решил похожую задачу следуюшим образом:

my_logging.py:

```
import os
import datetime
import errno
import logging.config
import logging.handlers

import yaml
    
def mkdir_p(path):
    try:
        os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)  # Python>3.2
    except TypeError:
        try:
            os.makedirs(path)
        except OSError as exc: # Python >2.5
            if exc.errno == errno.EEXIST and os.path.isdir(path):
                pass
            else: raise


class EvalFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        fn = eval(os.path.expandvars(kwargs['filename']))
        mkdir_p(os.path.dirname(fn))
        kwargs['filename'] = fn
        logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, **kwargs)

def setup_logging(
    config_file='logging.yml', 
    default_level=logging.INFO,
    env_key_config='LOGGING_CONFIG'
):
    """Setup logging configuration

    """
    path = config_file
    value = os.getenv(env_key_config, None)
    if value:
        path = value
    if os.path.exists(path):
        with open(path, 'rt') as f:
            config = yaml.load(f.read())
        logging.config.dictConfig(config)
    else:
        logging.basicConfig(level=default_level)
```

logging.yml:

```
---
version: 1
disable_existing_loggers: False
formatters:
    default:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"
    simple:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-8s - %(message)s"
    short:
        format: "%(asctime)s - %(message)s"
    message_only:
        format: "%(message)s"

handlers:
    console:
        class: logging.StreamHandler
        level: DEBUG
        formatter: simple
        stream: ext://sys.stdout

    debug_file_handler:
        class: my_logging.EvalFileHandler
        level: DEBUG            
        formatter: simple
        filename: "__import__('datetime').datetime.now().strftime('$HOME/log/%Y/%m/%Y%m%d-db_jiramatic-debug.log')"
        encoding: utf8

    info_file_handler:
        class: my_logging.EvalFileHandler
        level: INFO            
        formatter: simple
        filename: "__import__('datetime').datetime.now().strftime('$HOME/log/%Y/%m/%Y%m%d-db_jiramatic.log')"
        encoding: utf8

    error_file_handler:
        class: my_logging.EvalFileHandler
        level: ERROR            
        formatter: simple
        filename: "__import__('datetime').datetime.now().strftime('$HOME/log/%Y/%m/%Y%m%d-db_jiramatic-errors.log')"
        encoding: utf8

loggers:
    my_project:
        level: INFO
#        handlers: [console, info_file_handler, error_file_handler, debug_file_handler]
        handlers: [console, info_file_handler, error_file_handler]
        propagate: no

root:
    level: INFO
    handlers: [console, info_file_handler, error_file_handler]
```

потом в основном скрипте:

```
import my_logging

my_logging.setup_logging(config_file='/path/to/logging.yml')
logger = logging.getLogger('my_project')
```